# Dot product terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, terminology, inner-products

How would you grammatically correctly describe the computation of the dot product of two n-dimensional vectors.

Is this correct:

We multiply the corresponding elements of the two vectors. Then we sum the products together.

Comment: Sure, though a simple example or two does way more than a sentence could, in my opinion. (So don't stress on the verbiage too much.)

Comment: I would call them components rather than elements since elements typically refer to members of a set. I don't think it matters that much though.

Comment: I think you may be on to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corresponding to what? To be more precise, I would say multiply the components that have the same index and them take the sum.